# When, if ever, should characters like { and } (curly braces) be percent-encoded in URLs?

Tags: uri, percent-encoding, rfc3986

According to [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) the following characters are reserved and need to be percent-encoded in order to be used in a URI other than as their reserved uses:
`:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=`

Furthermore it specifies some characters that are specifically *unreserved*: `a-zA-Z0-9\-._~`

It seems clear that generally one should encode reserved characters (to prevent misinterpretation) and not encode unreserved characters (for readability), but **how should characters that do not fall into either category be handled?** For example `{` and `}` do not appear in either list, but they are standard ASCII characters.

Looking to modern browsers for guidance, it seems they sometimes have different behaviors.
For example, consider pasting the URL `https://www.google.com/search?q={` into the address bar of a web browser:

- Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m does not change it.
- Firefox 28.0 does not change it.
- Internet Explorer 9.0 does not change it.
- Safari 5.1.7 changes it to `https://www.google.com/search?q=%7B`

However, if one pastes `https://www.google.com/#q={` (removing "search" and changing the `?` to a `#`, making the character part of the fragment/hash rather than the query string) we find that:

- Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m changes it to `https://www.google.com/#q=%7B` (via JavaScript)
- Firefox 28.0 does not change it.
- Internet Explorer 9.0 does not change it.
- Safari 5.1.7 changes it to `https://www.google.com/#q=%7B` (before executing JavaScript)

Furthermore, when using JavaScript to perform the request asynchronously (i.e. using [this MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) modified to use a URL of `?q={`), the URL is not percent-encoded automatically. (I'm guessing this is because the XMLHttpRequest API assumes that the URL be encoded/escaped beforehand.)

I would like to (for a reason related to a bizarre customer requirement) use `{` and `}` in the filename portion of URLs without (1) breaking things and ideally also without (2) creating ugly-looking percent-encoded entries in the network panel of modern browsers' web inspectors/debuggers.

Answer (score 5):

(RFC [2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt))

You should be encoding any of the *unwise* section and the rfc gives the reason.

---

**additional information from the RFC**

Account for  `<` `>` `#` `%` primarily
any control characters `00-1F` and `7F`

also marked as *unwise* in the rfc: `"` `{` `}` `|` `\` `^` `[` `]` `` ` ``

if you are intending to allow for `#` to be in the querystring values then that's a special case, because a `#` is a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) of a uri.

Some characters which do not have to be encoded, are accepted either encoded or not such as `~`

There are 2 generally accepted encodings for  (space) `%20` and `+`

[Here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/12IFw1) with some of the test cases I'm using.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping for an answer from RFC3986, since that was supposed to supercede RFC2396, but I appreciate your response. Appendix D says `Section 2, on characters, has been rewritten to explain what characters are reserved, when they are reserved, and why they are reserved, even when they are not used as delimiters by the generic syntax....` and I guess ironically it's the rewriting that's caused the ambiguity for me.